# Python - Calculating a rolling mode on a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, mode, rolling-computation

I have a dataset that is reporting values for a specific date, that can then be updated on subsequent dates, thus creating 2 columns, `Date` and `Reported_Date`, for each `Reported_Value`. There is a separate `ID` field that is my dataframe's index. I want to calculate the mode and max for the last 5 reported dates. I know I can use `dataset['Reported_Value'].rolling(5).max()` to calculate the max, but trying rolling with mode leads to an error, `'Rolling' object has no attribute 'mode'`. Does anyone know how this could be achieved? Is there also a way to have it only compute across one Date? So that the first few values of `2021-12-02` weren't using `2021-12-01` values?

Example DataFrame:

```
    ID    Date          Reported_Date    Reported_Value    Max_Last_5_Reported_Days
     1    2021-12-01    2021-12-10                   5                 NaN
     2    2021-12-01    2021-12-11                   6                 NaN
     3    2021-12-01    2021-12-12                   5                 NaN
     4    2021-12-01    2021-12-13                   3                 NaN
     5    2021-12-01    2021-12-14                   2                 6
     6    2021-12-01    2021-12-15                   11                11
     7    2021-12-01    2021-12-16                   7                 11
     8    2021-12-01    2021-12-17                   5                 11
     9    2021-12-01    2021-12-18                   6                 11
     10   2021-12-01    2021-12-19                   7                 11
     11   2021-12-02    2021-12-10                   2                 7
     12   2021-12-02    2021-12-11                   3                 7
     13   2021-12-02    2021-12-12                   2                 7
     14   2021-12-02    2021-12-13                   4                 7
     15   2021-12-02    2021-12-14                   4                 4
     16   2021-12-02    2021-12-15                   4                 4
     17   2021-12-02    2021-12-16                   3                 4
     18   2021-12-02    2021-12-17                   4                 4
     19   2021-12-02    2021-12-18                   2                 4
     20   2021-12-02    2021-12-19                   4                 4
```

Desired DataFrame:

```
    ID    Date          Reported_Date    Reported_Value    Max_Last_5_Report_Days   Mode_L5RD
     1    2021-12-01    2021-12-10                   5                 NaN             NaN
     2    2021-12-01    2021-12-11                   6                 NaN             NaN
     3    2021-12-01    2021-12-12                   5                 NaN             NaN
     4    2021-12-01    2021-12-13                   3                 NaN             NaN
     5    2021-12-01    2021-12-14                   2                 6               5
     6    2021-12-01    2021-12-15                   11                11              NaN
     7    2021-12-01    2021-12-16                   6                 11              NaN
     8    2021-12-01    2021-12-17                   5                 11              NaN
     9    2021-12-01    2021-12-18                   6                 11              6
     10   2021-12-01    2021-12-19                   6                 11              6
     11   2021-12-02    2021-12-10                   2                 NaN             NaN
     12   2021-12-02    2021-12-11                   3                 NaN             NaN
     13   2021-12-02    2021-12-12                   2                 NaN             NaN
     14   2021-12-02    2021-12-13                   4                 NaN             NaN
     15   2021-12-02    2021-12-14                   4                 4               4
     16   2021-12-02    2021-12-15                   4                 4               4
     17   2021-12-02    2021-12-16                   3                 4               4
     18   2021-12-02    2021-12-17                   4                 4               4
     19   2021-12-02    2021-12-18                   2                 4               4
     20   2021-12-02    2021-12-19                   4                 4               4
```

I'm not sure how I would convey that there are multiple mode values, so they're listed as NaN in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`groupby` "Date" and use `rolling_max` for max for last 5 days; apply `scipy.stats.mode` for mode:

```
from scipy.stats import mode
rolling_obj = df.groupby('Date')['Reported_Value'].rolling(5)
df['Max_Last_5_Report_Days'] = rolling_obj.max().droplevel(0)
df['Mode_L5RD'] = rolling_obj.apply(lambda x: mode(x)[0]).droplevel(0)
```

Output:

```
    ID        Date Reported_Date  Reported_Value  Max_Last_5_Reported_Days  \
0    1  2021-12-01    2021-12-10               5                       NaN   
1    2  2021-12-01    2021-12-11               6                       NaN   
2    3  2021-12-01    2021-12-12               5                       NaN   
3    4  2021-12-01    2021-12-13               3                       NaN   
4    5  2021-12-01    2021-12-14               2                       6.0   
5    6  2021-12-01    2021-12-15              11                      11.0   
6    7  2021-12-01    2021-12-16               7                      11.0   
7    8  2021-12-01    2021-12-17               5                      11.0   
8    9  2021-12-01    2021-12-18               6                      11.0   
9   10  2021-12-01    2021-12-19               7                      11.0   
10  11  2021-12-02    2021-12-10               2                       7.0   
11  12  2021-12-02    2021-12-11               3                       7.0   
12  13  2021-12-02    2021-12-12               2                       7.0   
13  14  2021-12-02    2021-12-13               4                       7.0   
14  15  2021-12-02    2021-12-14               4                       4.0   
15  16  2021-12-02    2021-12-15               4                       4.0   
16  17  2021-12-02    2021-12-16               3                       4.0   
17  18  2021-12-02    2021-12-17               4                       4.0   
18  19  2021-12-02    2021-12-18               2                       4.0   
19  20  2021-12-02    2021-12-19               4                       4.0   

    Max_Last_5_Report_Days  Mode_L5RD  
0                      NaN        NaN  
1                      NaN        NaN  
2                      NaN        NaN  
3                      NaN        NaN  
4                      6.0        5.0  
5                     11.0        2.0  
6                     11.0        2.0  
7                     11.0        2.0  
8                     11.0        2.0  
9                     11.0        7.0  
10                     NaN        NaN  
11                     NaN        NaN  
12                     NaN        NaN  
13                     NaN        NaN  
14                     4.0        2.0  
15                     4.0        4.0  
16                     4.0        4.0  
17                     4.0        4.0  
18                     4.0        4.0  
19                     4.0        4.0
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Is there an easy way to flag when there is no mode? For the cases when all 5 values are unique; it's currently just return the first value.

Comment: @Dave I see what you mean but I don't know if it's possible with a simple one liner. Maybe we could count each value and see if there are ties and flag ties. But is your expected outcome the outcome you actually want? It has NaN values when there should be a mode.

Comment: Not so much that I want it to be NaN, just a way to indicate to someone that there is a tie. Could you use a similar approach as your solution to count the % of the values for the  last 5 days that is the chosen mode? That way, a frequency of .2 would indicate all values were unique.

Answer (score 0):

Mode is not a predefined function, however you can apply a custom function using `rolling(5).apply(custom_function)`. For your case that could be

```py
dataset['Reported_Value'].rolling(5).apply(lamba s: s.mode())
```